# Does cURL to https URLs require SSL certificate installed on the server?

Tags: ssl, curl, https

I am trying to test a `cURL` command from my server. The command is requesting a `JSON` response from a URL that is `https`.

The `cURL` seems to be stuck, with no response and it doesn't time out.

However, I have tested it from my local machine and the `cURL` command works fine.

Do I need an SSL certificate installed on the server for it be able to send `cURL` commands to an `https` URL?

Comment: There seems to be a general miss understanding here. Simple truth is that you cannot start an https service without such certificate. It does not have to be a signed one, you can sign it yourself if you are only interested in the encryption, but you cannot start without.

Comment: However this should not be an issue. You can get a free but perfectly fine certificate from the "Let's encrypt" project: https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: I don't think I have an SSL certificate installed on my server, so then it is a problem invoking an `https` URL? Although I don't fully understand `https`, but it puzzles me why I should need a certificate to connect? It is the server's SSL certificate that should be in question.

Comment: As said before: you simply cannot start the https server without. The server simply has no means to encrypt without a certificate. It may well be that you do not know that you have one installed, maybe it is a packaged "snake oil certificate". Just take a look into your http server configuration and look! This is no voodoo science!

Comment: Lol "Snake oil certificate"

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need an SSL cert to send a command like curl via https (unless your server uses two way ssl).

You **DO** need one at the other end for the https server that receives the command from curl.

However if it's a self signed cert then it may not be recognised by curl and you may get an error instead of a successful connection.

The fact the process is hanging suggests a network/connectivity issue rather than an SSL issue. Can you telnet to the machine using port 443 or does that hang too?

```
telnet www.example.com 443
```

Should respond.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a REST client URL, provided to me by a hosted service of Elastic search. I get `nodename nor servname provided, or not known` when I do `telnet`